# What can I do about this damaged area in my doorframe?

Tags: repair, doors, frame

My first house.  Noticed that the area of the doorframe where the strike plate should be is quite worn, and of course, there is no striker[image: image of damaged doorframe]  What are my options here?  Do I need to have the entire frame replaced?  Can a section be removed and replaced with new wood?

I checked for similar posts and although these are close, they aren't exactly the same
[damaged door frame](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119961/damaged-door-frame)
[Is this door striker and lock safe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/96893/is-this-door-striker-and-lock-safe)

Comment: it depends how far the damage goes

Comment: Was there a break-in (either by thieves or maybe cops)?  Guess you might not know since you just moved in, but this looks very much like somebody kicked the door in at some point.  Depending on where you live, if it was the police, they may be expected to pay for the repairs.  Might be hard to claim that if it was a previous occupant though.  (Unless maybe the reason the place was available is because the previous occupant was arrested and is now in prison maybe?)

Comment: If @DarrelHoffman's hypothesis was the case, you might also want to reinforce that area a bit, perhaps an additional steel plate on the inside (as long as that is very firmly anchored into the frame or wall).

Comment: While you're at it, double-check the hinge side of the door as well.  You might have hidden damage behind there as well.

Answer (score 12):

I would remove the door trim on the right hand side of the picture.

Cut out maybe 1 to 2 feet of the damage piece and replace it, using long screws to hold it.

Make a new striker hole and replace the trim.

Will probably not be as strong as replacing the whole piece, but it will depend on how strong you want or need the door catch to be.

Comment: It comes down to what security you want.  Right now it is I'll huff and blow your door down type.  Replacing with a piece with screws and maybe glue should give you at least it broke my leg kicking it down.

Comment: @dougk You can delete your comments and the retype your first one without the "rude...".  Two feet of wood and screws and gorilla wood glue will be pretty darn strong.  New frame = new door and possibly new threshold.

Comment: @JACK thanks and will do

Comment: This is an entry door on the rear of the house. I have a security system, but am also aware that if someone wants in enough they will get in. replacing 2 or more feet of the door frame is probably what I need. I'll leave this open for 24 hours and accept it as an answer. Appreciate the help

Comment: Suggest adding a new strike plate as well. That may have been implied, but it should be explicitly listed.

Answer (score 11):

Non-standard method, but it should be strong:

The idea here is to fasten the striker into something solid (the wood pillar) on the left) and not to the damaged door frame.

Remove wood from pillar so it is flush with the frame.

[image]

Cut 5mm thick sheet metal into a shape that makes a striker, fasten to pillar with screws ("x")

[image]

Replace the wood that was cut off from the pillar, and do some finishing.

[image]

As an example of a related thing I did:

It was a very old door, difficult and expensive to replace. One day, thieves broke in. That's how I discovered the lock side of the door was actually full of holes, which had been plugged with plaster over the decades (probably centuries) and painted over. It was well done, with who knows how many coats of paint on top, so I didn't see it, but the lock was screwed into plaster, so it broke easily.

Since the back of the door was flat, I simply reinforced the whole door with plywood, and fastened the lock into that with carriage bolts.

The idea is to not fasten the thieves' target to a fragile repaired area. This allows to make an aesthetic repair without worrying too much about strength.

Comment: Good idea.  It would be quite strong also, probably stronger than repairing the wood.

Comment: I have also done similar but used a commercially available Stryker plate that was about 8” tall, this is stronger and a great idea.

Comment: One note: The sheet metal strike plate will need to extend toward the inside of the house and be bent around a bit to A) look nice, and B) make the latch slide into place easily. I envision that a square edge as drawn would make it more difficult to close the door, potentially unintentionally leaving it completely unlatched.

Comment: Yes, it will need to be worked into a proper shape. Proper fit is important, some latches are really picky. I didn't bother to draw it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cut out the damaged parts.

Depending on your experience and skills, replace the excised pieces with whatever combination of filler and hand-made substitutes for metal, plaster or wood seems to suit the scenario.